# Passing object parameter to WCF

Tags: wcf, object

DataContract as :-

```
namespace AssemblyA
{
    public class Person                                 
    {     
        public string FirstName {get;set;}
        public string LastName {get;set;}                             
    }                                                              
}
```

Service is as follows:-

```
[ServiceContract]            
public interface IServer      
{ 
    [OperationContract]  
    Person GetPerson(); 

    [OperationContract] 
    Person UpdatePerson( Person person )             
}
```

Client side:-

```
using AssemblyA; 

namespace AssemblyB 
{
    class Program     
    {         
        static void Main(string[] args)         
        {             
            IServer server = factory.CreateChannel(); 
            Person person = server.GetPerson(); 
            person.FirstName = "Kilroy";       
            person.LastName = "";
            Person p = server.UpdatePerson(person);
            String str = p.LastName; 
        }    
    }
}
```

I have two problems:-

1. I am setting LastName property to blank and called GetPerson method. After that when I am checking for LastName property it is coming as nothing instead of blank.
2. Second Problem is if I made change in Person class as follows:-

   ```
   public class Person                                             
   {                                                 
       String _FirstName;   
       String _LastName;                                 
       public string FirstName 
       {
           get{}
           set
           { 
               _FirstName=value;
               _LastName="XYZ";
           }
       }

       public string LastName { get;set; }  
   }
   ```

After this I Changed my Client as :-

```
IServer server = factory.CreateChannel(); 
Person person = server.GetPerson(); 
person.FirstName = "Kilroy";       
person.LastName = "abc";
Person p = server.UpdatePerson(person);
String str = p.LastName;
```

then in str it shows "XYZ" instead of "abc". But I am expecting "abc" from it.

Please advice as I have to use it in my project.

Comment: Is the complete code? Where's the DataContract attribute on your Person class?

Comment: You _really_ need to put comments in comments and not in your question details. It really muddies your question and makes it difficult for anyone referencing the question in the future to figure out what the problem and solution is.

Answer (score 0):

As for your second problem, you have a property LastName and a field _LastName, they are not related. In your client code, you set FirstName, this sets the _LastName **field** to "abc", then you set the LastName **property**.

Now you have Person class with a field _LastName set to "XYZ" and a property LastName set to "abc".